# mysql Prepared statement, neither error or data in db

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I am trying to setup my database handling with prepared statement, but I am kinda stuck. I don't get any error msg to work with and data is not put into the db. I am a little afraid this is just a stupid mistake, but I'd appreciate if you could help me.

I am using php with a mysql database.

Below you can see the function to create a person. getConnection() will open the database connection onto the variable $link and return true if no error occur.

```
public function createUser($userName, $password)
{
    if($this->getConnection() === true) {
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->link, 'INSERT INTO users (Username, Login, Password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $userName, $userName, $password);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
    $this->link->close();   
}
```

If you have an idea, what wrong, I'd be more than happy. I am open to sugestions.

Thanks in advance

/Pyracell

Comment: Why are the insert values all question marks?

Comment: Well, it's probably not returning errors because you didn't tell it to return errors. Add `mysqli_error($stmt);` after your `execute` command and see if there's anything.

Comment: @redelman431 From what I know, that's the idea with prepared statements. At least from the examples I have seen.

Comment: @Palladium I have added mysqli_stmt_error($stmt); after my execute. (the one you line you gave me gave an error itself) Still no errors.

Comment: @Pyracell And what if `$this->getConnection()` does not return `true`?

Comment: @jeroen I've just tried making an else statement with redirect. No redirect is happening.

Comment: why not [*use PDO*](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/) ?

Comment: Of course you don't get any errors, you don't check if the prepare or the execute succeeded, and you don't query the database for any error messages.

Comment: @alfasin as long as he's not using mysql_* it's not a big problem, unless he decides to migrate to another DB in the future.

Comment: @GordonM you're right! but I also like the `Named Parameters` better ;)

Comment: @alfasin I will consider PDO, but for now I'll just need the site to be functional.

Comment: @all thanks for your help. John C's debugging overkill located my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQLi won't always throw an error if a MySQL query fails, so if things aren't working you'll have to check at each step for what went wrong. For this [`mysqli_error()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) and [`mysqli_stmt_error()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.error.php) are your friends.

As an overkill example of error-checking (for debugging purposes, it could be scaled back once you have things working), something like:

```php
public function createUser($userName, $password)
{
    if($this->getConnection() === true) {
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->link, 'INSERT INTO users (Username, Login, Password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
        if ($stmt != FALSE) {
            $bind = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $userName, $userName, $password);
            if ($bind == FALSE) {
                echo 'Bind failed: '.mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);              
            } else {
                $exec = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                if ($exec == FALSE) {
                    echo 'Execute failed: '.mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
                }
            }
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        } else {
            echo 'Prepare failed: '.mysqli_error($this->link);
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Failed connecting to database: '.mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $this->link->close();   
}
```

Comment: Thanks John C. Worked like a charm. My function hashing the password failed due to a session, and returned "null" instead of the hashstring. the password field in my db cannot be false, therefor execute failed. Thanks a lot.